# Dimension of irreducible components of $f^{-1}(X)$, where $X$ is a hypersurface

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand the following problem from [Gathmann's algebraic geometry notes](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2019/alggeom-2019.pdf):If $f:\mathbb{P}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^m$ is a morphism and $X\subset\mathbb{P}^m$ is a hypersurface then every irreducible component of $f^{-1}(X)$ has dimension at least $n-1$.

$X$ a hypersurface means it has dimension $m-1$. And $f$ a morphism means it is given locally by polynomials. Further, $f$ is continuous, and so $f^{-1}(X)$ is closed in $\mathbb{P}^n$. My only idea is to start with a chain of irreducible closed subsets $X_0\subsetneq X_1\subsetneq\cdots\subsetneq X_{n-1}=X$ and take the preimage. But I'm not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is a hypersurface, it is given by one homogeneous equation, i.e.
$$ X = \{\, [x_0: \dotsc: x_m] \in \mathbb P^m \, | \, p(x_0, \dotsc, x_m) = 0 \,\}$$
for some homogeneous polynomial $p \in \mathbb C[x_0, \dotsc, x_m]$. The preimage $f^{-1}(X)$ is then the vanishing locus of
$$ f^* p = p(f_0, \dotsc, f_m) \in \mathbb C[y_0, \dotsc, y_n],$$
where $f_i \in \mathbb C[y_0, \dotsc, y_n]$ are the homogeneous polynomials defining $f$.